# set command that does not export variable after BAT script finishes running

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If I have this `doit.bat` script:

```
@echo off
set MY_VAL=3
echo %MY_VAL%
```

Then:

```
> doit
3
> echo %MY_VAL%
3
```

In other words, by default the `set` command persists variables to the calling environment. This is different from Unix, where you have to `source` a script in order for that to happen.

I am trying to figure out how to be able to do the following:

- Set variables in a `.bat` script but not have them persist to the environment after the script finishes - that is, have Windows act more like Unix.
- At the same time, I still would like those variables to be set for any environments forked while the `.bat` script is running - that is, the equivalent of setting the variables via the Unix `export` command.

Is there a way to do this, either via some other `cmd` command or some option to `set`?  I search SO and docs but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please read the tag info before you apply tags! I am quite sure you are not working with MS-**DOS**, do you? Anyway, for your first point (localised environment), the commands you are looking for are `setlocal` and `endlocal`; so usually there is a `setlocal` command on top of the batch file (below `@echo off`); `endlocal` is considered as optional because there is an implicit `endlocal` done when the batch file is terminated. For your second point (forked environments), there is no native command to accomplish that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
==> SETLOCAL /?
Begins localization of environment changes in a batch file.  Environment
changes made after SETLOCAL has been issued are local to the batch file.
ENDLOCAL must be issued to restore the previous settings.  When the end
of a batch script is reached, an implied ENDLOCAL is executed for any
outstanding SETLOCAL commands issued by that batch script.
…
```

Or read [SETLOCAL: Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).

You could use next `doit.bat` script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set MY_VAL=3
echo %MY_VAL%
```